# Angular mentions with redirect url - how to add url link to selected element from angular mention

Tags: angular7

How I can add url link to selected element from angular mentions.

any suggestion on this ?

My code is

Comment: Forgot adding your code?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and share us what you have tried so far.